# Refer to previously selected column in select gives error 1054

Tags: mysql, select

In

```
select sum(orders) as total, count(*) as c, c / total as average
```

It gives an "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column..."

Is there any way to achieve this backreferencing without the very annoying work of wrapping the select in another select?

I imagine this is a duplicate but I haven't been able to find it, so, here's how I would ask it.

Comment: You need to repeat the expression as `count(*)/sum(orders)`

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid so you have to compute everything twice and break DRYness?

Answer (score 0):

The aliased columns don't exist until the query is completed, so you can't use them in the same query.

Just repeat the expressions in the calculation:

```
select 
  sum(orders) as total, 
  count(*) as c, 
  count(*)  / sum(orders) as average
from 
  yourtable
```

Or do the select and then the calculation:

```
select 
  s.total, s.c, s.c / s.total as average 
from
  (select 
     sum(orders) as total, 
     count(*) as c 
   from <yourtable>) s
```

Comment: Aren't both of those options terrible? The first is very not DRY and requires duplicate work of potentially computationally expensive work (unless MySQL is magic and caches it), the second is hard to maintain and hard to modify and use on the fly (e.g. I often need to sometimes see the original data and sometimes the wrapped data, so have to hack it back and forth or duplicate it, which again is not DRY)

Comment: Yep, they both stink, but that's the way it works with most DBMSs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `avg` function:

```
select sum(orders) as total, count(*) as c, avg(orders) as average
```

Based on the column name, I assume you really want the average and not "1 / average" as expressed in your question.

Comment: It was a toy example, in real life I'm doing `sum(if(folders_scanned > 0, 1, 0)) `.

Comment: @djechlin . . . If you are using MySQL that's silly.  Much easier to do `sum(folders_scanned > 0)`.  You can also just do the average that way as well.

Comment: You'er right, the "if" is extraneous. I don't know what you mean by "do the average the same way", it looks like I'll still have to do the `sum(folders_scanned>0)` twice.

Comment: @djechlin . . . `avg(folders_scanned > 0)`.